# Joomla registration and activation

Tags: email, joomla, registration, activation

When the configuration is set to admin activation: When a person registers, the admin does not receive an email at first, the user receives an email with an activation link. When the user clicks this activation link only then does the admin get an email notification that a new user has registered and their account needs to be activated. After admin activates the users account, the user receives an email notifying them that their account has been activated.

We would like to cut half of these steps. We need the functionality to be as follows :

When the user registers admin should receive an email notification that a new user has registered and the users account needs to be activated. At this point the user should not receive an activation email. Only after admin has activated the users account will the user receive an email with their login details and notified that their account has been activated.

Basically we are trying to ONLY have admin activation and NOT user double opt in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User registration/activation emails & admin emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338595/user-registration-activation-emails-admin-emails)

Comment: Deliberate duplicate of your question four days prior?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to users >> manage. Then click the options button and change the settings as follows:

1. New User account activation: Administrator
2. Notification Mail to Administrators: Yes

The rest of the settings you will have to change to your preference.

Comment: All the settings are correct:

New User account activation: Administrator
Notification Mail to Administrators: Yes

We are trying to ONLY have admin activation and NOT user double opt in.
We don't want the user to have to do anything or click any links. They must sign up, then only admin gets an email saying a new user has registered and admin activates the users account, and only THEN the user should receive an email to say their account has been activated.